# Classic ASP on IIS delivers Error Document instead of content on HTTP 410 Gone

Tags: iis, asp-classic, http-status-codes

I’ve got a Classic ASP application running on IIS (6/7) servers. When a page is requested that won’t be accessible any longer, I want to send a `Response.Status = "410 Gone"` but still deliver some sort of `ErrorDocument`. It seems that browsers halt retrieving as soon as they get a 410.

Except for IE, all browsers display the same “The page you requested was removed”, so I guess it’s a server setting. In .NET, there seems to be `TrySkipIisCustomErrors`, but for Classic ASP, I’m actually quite confident it’s anywhere in the Error Pages feature in IIS Manager.

Can I tell my IIS to still deliver content, even when the actual URI is gone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your web application’s root directory, you have to add an attribute in the `web.config` file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough">
        …
    </httpErrors>
<system.webServer>
```

With `existingResponse` set to `PassThrough`, the response will be delivered if an existing response exists. There’s a nice [article on HTTP Errors at www.iis.net](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors).

There doesn’t need to be an `<error>` element, especially none on status code 410 (but of course you may add one).

Answer (score 1):

You could place a classic ASP page there that delivers the content and HTTP Status Code you want.

I tested this on IIS 7.5 with following code:

```
    <% Response.Status = "410 Gone" %>
    <html>
    <body>
    <h1>this is my content</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Firefox shows the content as is, not a generic error page.

**Update:**

You will have to disable custom errors for this to work. You can do this by adding following line to your web.config (into section configuration/system.web):

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

Otherwise, the default error page overrules your output. Classic ASP really doesn't seem to have anything like `TrySkipIisCustomErrors`.

Comment: Actually I am using a Classic ASP page on an IIS 7.5, and my code is not much different from yours, just more. But even with your snippet, nothing changes. Do you have a Error Page set in your IIS Manager?

Comment: Unfortunately, `customErrors mode="Off"` didn’t change anything. Even on different setups, the `customErrors` modes did not make any change. Thanks for the clue regarding `web.config` options, it led to the solution anyway.